# JNI problems with a shared object

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

well i am having problems with jni, i am trying to run an example code
i have in one side

```
HelloJNI.java
```

and

```
javatoc_HelloJNI.h
```

and in the other side in c

```
HelloJNI.cpp
```

all is fine until I try to make the .so
it gives me this error.

```
**/usr/bin/ld: error: /tmp/cc2Udvjs.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc which may                overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC**
```

so i am practically stuck in the creation of a .SO
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you consider doing what the message says and just recompiling with the –fPIC switch? Because that's actually all you have to do.

Comment: jajaja, well that's kind of my problem, i don't know the sintaxis to recompile it with -fPIC

Comment: Come off it. It's a compiler switch. Put it with the other compiler switches. This is not a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your compile options to add the -fPIC flag.

```
gcc   -fPIC -c cc2Udvjs.c

gcc  -shared -o libWhatever.so cc2Udvjs.o
```

https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/index.xml?style=printable&part=1&chap=3